# ¿por que me marca error en la palabra reservada As en C# con sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Buen día compañeros.
estaba realizando una consulta a una base de datos que tengo. pero hay un problema el cual no logro dar, el por que me da, el asunto es que tengo una consulta en sql server studio y ahi me retorna muy bien los datos que requiero al pasarlo a Visual studio con C# me da un error, la conexión la establece correctamente, pero el query no lo ejecuta. ya intente encerrando la parte del From (que es donde me da el error) con [] quitando la palabra 'AS' oh poniendo ambas ej. from [tabla as tb] y no logro dar con la solución.

ustedes que ya tienen más experiencia.
¿me pueden ayudar?

```
private List<datos> CargarDatos(string query="")
        {
            string sql = (query == "")
            ? "SELECT  CE.ID_USUARIO, PL.NOMBRES, PL.CORREO_E,UROL.ID_ROL , CAL.ID_ALCANCE" +
            "CROL.DESCRIPCION , CAL.DESCRIPCION" +
            "from CE_CAT_USUARIO as CE,PL_PERSONAL PL,CE_CAT_ROL  CROL,CE_USUARIO_ROL  UROL,CE_CAT_ALCANCE as CAL" +
            "where CE.ID_PERSONA = PL.ID_PERSONA AND CE.ID_USUARIO = UROL.ID_USUARIO AND UROL.ID_ROL = CROL.ID_ROL AND UROL.ID_ALCANCE = CAL.ID_ALCANCE"
            : query;
            SqlConnection connection = cn.ObtenerConexion();
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                // para que la consulta se ejecute
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                //para leer la tabla 
                SqlDataReader lector = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();

                while (lector.Read())
                {
                    datos d1 = new datos()
                    {
                        ID_USUARIO = int.Parse(lector[0].ToString()),
                        NOMBRES = lector[1].ToString(),
                        CORREO_E = lector[2].ToString(),
                        ID_ROL = int.Parse(lector[3].ToString()),
                        ID_ALCANCE = int.Parse(lector[4].ToString()),
                        descripcion_alcance = lector[5].ToString(),
                        descripcion_rol = lector[6].ToString()
                    };
                    datos.Add(d1); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                "Error inesperado: " + e.Message,
                "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            return datos;

        }
```

cualquier ayuda será muy bien recibida. :) de antemano muchas gracias.

el error que me muestra es:

**ERROR INESPERADO: SINTAXIS INCORRECTA CERCA DE 'CE'**

Comment: hasta donde sé, puedes remover el "as" del query, y toma como alias el texto que pongas después

Comment: @L.Ronquillo, Si. también ya le intente así, pero marca error de todas maneras.

Comment: ¿puedes editar la pregunta, enseñando la excepción que está produciendo? así nos damos una idea de que pueda ser

Comment: @L.Ronquillo sip. ya le agregue el error que me lanza

Comment: en tu query `SELECT  CE.ID_USUARIO, PL.NOMBRES, PL.CORREO_E,UROL.ID_ROL , CAL.ID_ALCANCE" +"CROL.DESCRIPCION , CAL.DESCRIPCION` no veo una `,` entre `CAL.ID_ALCANCE` y `CROL.DESCRIPCION`, ¿podrá ser eso?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo ya la puse pero no, no era eso. aun me marca error :C

Comment: Si concatenas `"tabla as t"+"WHERE"` obtendrás `"tabla as tWHERE"` cuando realmente necesitas `"tabla as t WHERE"` . Añade espacios a la cadena donde haya que separar (al principio o al final).

Comment: @Sal oh si, ya los separe, y también en lugar de re-nombrarlos estoy usando el nombre de la tabla así. 
Tabla.campo y pues haber ahorita si logro algo ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola puedes probar asi

```
string sql = (query == "")
            ? @"SELECT  CE.ID_USUARIO, PL.NOMBRES, PL.CORREO_E,UROL.ID_ROL , CAL.ID_ALCANCE,
            CROL.DESCRIPCION , CAL.DESCRIPCION
            from CE_CAT_USUARIO as CE,PL_PERSONAL PL,CE_CAT_ROL  CROL,CE_USUARIO_ROL  UROL,CE_CAT_ALCANCE as CAL
            where CE.ID_PERSONA = PL.ID_PERSONA AND CE.ID_USUARIO = UROL.ID_USUARIO AND UROL.ID_ROL = CROL.ID_ROL AND UROL.ID_ALCANCE = CAL.ID_ALCANCE"
            : query;
```

Te explico tu estabas poniendo el query sin espacios osea tu lo mandabas asi

```
SELECT  CE.ID_USUARIO, PL.NOMBRES, PL.CORREO_E,UROL.ID_ROL , CAL.ID_ALCANCE,CROL.DESCRIPCION , CAL.DESCRIPCIONfrom CE_CAT_USUARIO as CE,PL_PERSONAL PL,CE_CAT_ROL  CROL,CE_USUARIO_ROL  UROL,CE_CAT_ALCANCE as CALwhere CE.ID_PERSONA = PL.ID_PERSONA AND CE.ID_USUARIO = UROL.ID_USUARIO AND UROL.ID_ROL = CROL.ID_ROL AND UROL.ID_ALCANCE = CAL.ID_ALCANCE
```

Si tu copias y pegas lo de arriba te va a dar error en el sql

La mejor forma de poner strings largos es con @"" y asi te permite tener multilinea

Comment: ohhhh si no sabia que se tenia que poner el @. pero lo probé y ya funciona. muchas gracias :) @Jorge Luis

Comment: De nada @lemuelAyanotfuentesAyala te puse la explicación

Answer (score 0):

no pude hacer el renombramiento pero hice lo siguiente y me dio el resultado.

```
private List<datos> CargarDatos(string query="")
        {
            string sql = (query == "")
            ? " SELECT CE_CAT_USUARIO.ID_USUARIO, PL_PERSONAL.NOMBRES, PL_PERSONAL.CORREO_E,CE_USUARIO_ROL.ID_ROL , CE_CAT_ALCANCE.ID_ALCANCE," +
            " CE_CAT_ROL.DESCRIPCION, CE_CAT_ALCANCE.DESCRIPCION "+
            " FROM CE_CAT_USUARIO, PL_PERSONAL, CE_CAT_ROL, CE_USUARIO_ROL, CE_CAT_ALCANCE "+
            " WHERE  CE_CAT_USUARIO.ID_PERSONA =PL_PERSONAL.ID_PERSONA "+
            " AND "+
            " CE_CAT_USUARIO.ID_USUARIO = CE_USUARIO_ROL.ID_USUARIO "+
            " AND "+
            " CE_USUARIO_ROL.ID_ROL = CE_CAT_ROL.ID_ROL "+
            " AND "+
            " CE_USUARIO_ROL.ID_ALCANCE = CE_CAT_ALCANCE.ID_ALCANCE"
            :query;

            SqlConnection connection = cn.ObtenerConexion();
            connection.Open();

            try
            {
                // para que la consulta se ejecute
                SqlCommand sqlcom = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                //para leer la tabla 
                SqlDataReader lector = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();

                while (lector.Read())
                {
                    datos d1 = new datos()
                    {
                        ID_USUARIO = int.Parse(lector[0].ToString()),
                        NOMBRES = lector[1].ToString(),
                        CORREO_E = lector[2].ToString(),
                        ID_ROL = int.Parse(lector[3].ToString()),
                        ID_ALCANCE = int.Parse(lector[4].ToString()),
                        descripcion_alcance = lector[5].ToString(),
                        descripcion_rol = lector[6].ToString()
                    };
                    datos.Add(d1); 
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(
                "Error inesperado: " + e.Message,
                "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                MessageBoxIcon.Error);
               
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }

            return datos;

        }
```

NO ES LA MEJOR FORMA por que es mucho código y es muy revoltoso. pero es la forma en que lo logre. algo que cabe recalcar como uno en los comentarios me dijo son las comas (,) pues en donde estaba llamando los campos que ocupaba me faltaba una coma en la ultima linea (también me lo comentaron). espero y más adelante alguien sepa como renombrar en C# por que le intente tanto con 'AS' como con 'rename to' y ninguna me dejo. espero les sea útil.

Comment: Considera utilizar JOINS en vez de la vieja sintaxis. Te dará menos problemas y más versatilidad a futuro. También busca sugerencias de formato de código SQL para que sea más fácil de leer.